# XHR doesn't work because "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: jquery, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, xmlhttprequest, http-method

I'm working on a API-Server with Rails 3 wich is pretty handy so far but I'm running across a error all the time and I'm not sure wether it is because of my Apache Setup or the Rails App.

When I try to do a HTTP DELETE or PUT request on http://sample.domain/uri/id via XHR, curl or HTTP-Client.app Rails or Apache responds with 404 or 403 (depends on the client. I think because of cors)  and the Safari developer console responds with

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sample.domain/uri/id. Origin http://web.client/ is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I'm using mod_rack aka mod_rails on a Apache2 and my vhost actually contains this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With
```

The Apache error_log responds with the following error:

```
[Sat Oct 30 01:37:34 2010] [error] [client 22.222.222.22] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/rails/folder/public, referer: http://web.client/
```

Rails development.log responds with

```
Started OPTIONS "/uri/id" for 84.190.123.140 at 2010-10-30 03:18:42 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/uri/id"):
```

And here I'm nor sure why the OPTIONS call comes trough because I thought this would only be the preflight and for sure there is no route for OPTIONS because I want to respond to DELETE

If you have any idea on how to fix this problem please share it with me.

Thank you very much David

Comment: I'm not sure I fully appreciate your problem, but it **sounds** suspiciously similar to the legendary [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Have you verified that a straight up `OPTIONS` works?  Eg, using `curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost/uri/id`?

Comment: I'm more or less sure it is because of the sop but I thought I'd fixed it with my header settings. I'm not sure with OPTIONS because Rails should only respond to DELETE / PUT because I think the OPTIONS request is just the 'preflight'

Comment: is it possible that your clients are not setting the Origin header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to respond to the OPTIONS method. It is sent *before* the actual DELETE method to determine if sending a DELETE command is allowed - known as [preflighting](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request). You can control how long the permissions are valid with a [Access-Control-Max-Age](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#http-access-control-max-age) header.

In your response to OPTIONS is where you send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, etc.

Imagine if that wasn't the case. You'd be sending ACAO *after* you've already deleted the object. Which may or may not have been allowed.

For the origin server it is often best to either create an actual white list of servers that can post/delete, or parrot back the requesting server's domain name. A "*" essentially disables CORS and opens up the user to all sorts of attacks.

Answer (score 1):

In *nix systems you need first to include/enable "Headers" module in apache

**sudo a2enmod headers**

then, you need to include in your vhost the following line :

**Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"**

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a different issue.

You're doing the correct thing regarding the headers for CORS. Something else in your Apache configuration is denying the client. Apache doesn't care about same-origin policy at all, so your "client denied by server configuration" error will be because of an incorrect `Access` directive or something similar.

As suggested, make sure you can `curl -X OPTIONS http://sample.domain/uri/id` first.