# issuing DELETE request using XmlHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

hi guys below is my code and i am getting error on line setRequestHeaders

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#delete').click(function(){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("DELETE","https://server/v0/DTDG78/Test/Tulips.jpg",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token:", "AUTH_tkba87f3f9d9be428898ba362477d18");                    
 xmlhttp.send();
                });

            });
```

The Error message on console is

> > Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader] [Break On This Error]
>
> ...lhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token:',
>   'AUTH_tkba87f3f9d9be428898ba362477d18...

What am i missing or it is not possible at all ? any comments , suggestions code is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, why not let it handle the AJAX call for you?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://server/v0/DTDG78/Test/Tulips.jpg',
    type: 'DELETE',
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function( xhr) { 
        // Note: You probably do not need 'X-Auth-Token:', I've removed the colon 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "AUTH_tkba87f3f9d9be428898ba362477d18"); 
    },
    success: function( result) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nickb. i was doing it this way before but no response comes back from server

Comment: That's odd. You can try modifying your original code and removing the colon, see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Chorome Error is Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Comment: Also in firefox and chrome the method listed is not DELETE but OPTIONS

Comment: Googling your error message turns up some interesting results - [Apache might not be configured correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056855/xhr-doesnt-work-because-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin), or you are not abiding to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: i am sending it to openstack swift server which has the header of
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,